# OperationFailure: database error: not authorized for query on database.system.namespaces

Tags: django, mongodb, heroku, django-nonrel, django-syncdb

I am beginner lift with django mongodb on heroku [ addon : mongolab ].

```
heroku run python manage.py syncdb
```

Running `python manage.py syncdb` attached to terminal... up, run.2332
Creating tables ...

```
OperationFailure: database error: not authorized for query on database.system.namespaces consider editing privileges on the basis of data mongo
```

.

```
>use admin
>db.addUser({ user: "myadmin", pwd: "1234", roles: ["userAdminAnyDatabase"] })
```

but get:

```
Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to execute command
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Deployment heroku test this in here: [link](http://armadillo1.herokuapp.com/) ,but the error comes in: [link](http://armadillo1.herokuapp.com/admin/) , local works well the problem is generated in heroku deployment .

Comment: How did you log to the mongo shell? You need to authenticate with a privileged user.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku Postgres does not allow for user creation. You'll want to use the connection string provided in `DATABASE_URL`. Actions like creating/dropping DB's and creating users is prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more a heroku problem than a django problem. It appears to be that you're not allowed to add users on the mongodb instance; were you send a username and password to plug into the django settings?

Answer (score 0):

First you should connect to your mongodb terminal without any authentication, then you try to create user or user-role which you want to do.

check this link for more information. [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)